# Adding the share button in the default Tumblr mobile theme to a desktop theme

Tags: tumblr

I've noticed the default mobile / responsive theme Tumblr serves has 3 buttons under each post - **Share**, **Like** and **Reblog**...

[image: Tumblr Mobile Theme Buttons]

However, the [custom theme docs](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#like_and_reblog_buttons) only provide tags for 2 of these (Like and Reblog).

This button is in keeping with the other 2 and looks good. Is it possible to include it within a custom theme, rather than having to use a custom plugin or script (AddThis, ShareAnywhere etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no inherent `{ShareButton}` that provides similar functionality to the `{LikeButton}` and `{ReblogButton}`.

You'd have to use custom plugins and custom code to set it up.
Though most sharing outlets allow sharing links quite easily through URL intents.

see

- [Twitter Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)
- [Facebook Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)
- [Google+ Share Link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely add a Share This widget.

Here is some code I have from a theme where this is working:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
 <div class="sharethis-wrapper">
     <span st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'>
     </span>
 </div>
```

It is also possible to create a modal with links to other social media and have it triggered by a custom icon. See here: http://veritelouiseswimwear.tumblr.com/

Have you tried anything so far? We may need to see some code and then it would be possible to tweak it to work for you.

Comment: OP states: Is it possible to include it within a custom theme, rather than having to use a custom plugin or script (AddThis, ShareAnywhere etc.)?

Comment: Yeah I reread the question but I realise I have a solution for addthis, but thought it better to leave it in, as at least that solution works, and there is a solution for custom share button functionality but I think it would help to see some code, then I can edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, but as per question I'd like to see if there is basically some Tumblr tag like `{LikeButton}` that does the job.

Comment: Or a way to replicate the mobile theme function as per Tumblr's default implementaton.

Comment: Yeah it's not possible with a custom tumblr tag, but it can be done via hand coding.